# Reverse DNS record can't point to Domain name but it can point to IP

Tags: vpn, reverse-dns, ptr-record

I am using parallels plesk for hosting my websites,

Some days ago I tried to send emails from my mail server and the mails were going to spam,So i tried spam assassin to detect whats wrong. Here is output of that:

```
 pts rule name               description
---- ---------------------- --------------------------------------------------
 0.0 URIBL_BLOCKED          ADMINISTRATOR NOTICE: The query to URIBL was blocked.
                            See
                            http://wiki.apache.org/spamassassin/DnsBlocklists#dnsbl-block
                             for more information.
                            [URIs: xyz.org]
 0.0 HTML_MESSAGE           BODY: HTML included in message
 1.3 RDNS_NONE              Delivered to internal network by a host with no rDNS
```

So as per that I had come to know that I need to setup an RDNS for `xyz.org`, But it can't be done by my side; It should be done by my ISP.

So i had contacted them and told them to set an RDNS for my domain(`xyz.org`) on IP(say`1.2.3.4`).

That is It should output something like:

```
4.3.2.1.in-addr.arpa. TTL(86400) IN PTR smtp.xyz.org.
```

But Here is what they are saying to me: **Reverse DNS record can't point to Domain name but it can point to entire IP**

What is that?? I mean why can't it point to my domain name? it is right now pointing to somehing like: `pingaworks.managedns.org.`? Is that why I'm getting spam assassins error? Is there any simple way to create RDNS for your VPN using parallels plesk? also I'm the admin of server.

Also after further reading I had come to know that, RDNS is required if you're planning to have a mail server afterwards(and yes I'm planning for it); What should I do now?

BUT

I don't understand what my ISP is saying. Hope experts here will help me. Please.

Thanks in advance.

MOST Importantly:

```
How To setup RDNS for domain name?
```

I had wasted 96hrs on this, but without success.

Comment: Administration panels are off topic.

Answer (score 5):

Reverse DNS points an IP to a domain name. An ISP/Hosting company should own the IP range, and it should be no problem at all for them to create a reverse DNS entry for your IP, unless it's not just your IP (you're on shared hosting).

Should that be the case, you are not going to get anywhere. Your ISP/Hosting probably can get you your own individual IP, but I'll imagine you will be paying more for it.

Comment: No. it is my dedicated IP(according to them) but it's PTR is pointing to `pingaworks.managedns.org.` it should be to `smtp.xyz.org.`? what is wrong in PTR record?

Comment: I can't say without knowing what the IP is, but if that's what the RDNS lookup is returning, it means that if thye have updated the record for you it could still be propagating just like any other DNS record. The other possibility is that they have not updated the record.

Comment: well, Amazing!! I'm still getting(pingaworks.managedns.org) and BOTH of them are useless for me :)!

Comment: try this from a linux prompt: `dig @ns1.cmh.aotech.net -x 216.185.43.17`

Comment: Well, everything seems to be configured correctly, at least in terms of their server (hostopia|aotech) responding to RDNS requests. I'd say it's pretty obvious that they haven't completed your request, if that's not he answer you want.

Comment: Oh crap, just saw I missed a number :(

Comment: Yeah, it's pingaworks :/

Comment: stupid copy and paste.. anyhow, yeah, if that's your hosting company, they have not completed your request

Comment: Just one question, I had setup 3 different websites on that IP. does it matters? as long as RDNS is considered?

Comment: You will need to decide which domain and server name you want to be primary, as RDNS can have more than one IP to domain mapping, but it will return the answers in round robin order, which is not a good thing if you want your mail to be delivered. I would pick the domain you want your mailserver on, and set up the RDNS to point to the FQDN you will be using for the mail server.

Comment: Thanks mate. It was really helpful :). but can't accept this answer yet as it is an dedicated IP.

Comment: Well, whatever I say, the only people who will fix this issue are Aotech and /or Hostopia, best of luck :)