# What Does 'HELO_LH_HOME' Means In Spamassassin's result?

Tags: windows-server-2008, php, iis-7, spam, spamassassin

I'm trying to send emails from `PHPMailer` using `php` on my IIS server.

But My emails are going to spam, So I've used spamassasin to detect what is wrong?

and here is the result:

```
 pts rule name               description
---- ---------------------- --------------------------------------------------
 2.0 HELO_LH_HOME           HELO_LH_HOME
 0.0 HTML_MESSAGE           BODY: HTML included in message
 1.3 RDNS_NONE              Delivered to internal network by a host with no rDNS
```

Total Score :3.3

I know I can reduce 1.3 by adding RDNS record but currently I cant ([Here is why](https://serverfault.com/questions/646917/reverse-dns-record-cant-point-to-domain-name-but-it-can-point-to-ip))

So I will try to remove another 2.0 points, But I really Don't know what are these points for? and how to reduce them?

For More Information:

I'm using Parallels Plesk for managing my sites, any help, suugestions are welcome.

Can anyone please tell me how to overcome this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Your mailname seems to end with ".home" or ".lan". This makes spamassassin believe you're not a trust worthy mail source, hence the score of 2.0. Phpmailer apparently has a " $Hostname" variable you can set in order to use an specific hostname in the EHLO command:

http://phpmailer.worxware.com/?pg=properties

Comment: Well It looks right In My Mail Headers there is header `Received: from QS-257.home` But How can I do it in windows(parallels plesk)? +1.

Comment: Don't know why I though you had postfix somewhere in the neighbourhood... I edited my post to match phpmailer use case.

Comment: Of course changing the hostname of the machine is still an option.

Comment: BTW, you're not supposed to post non-professional topic here. ".home" makes me think this is not really professional stuffs.